# On the equivalence between $E^F$ and $\#(E)^{\#(F)}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $E$ and $F$ are finite sets, it can be argued that the set of all functions from $F$ to $E$ (denoted $E^F$)is also finite. In fact, $E^F \sim (\#E)^{(\#F)}$. (Note that $(\#E)^{(\#F)}$ is the $\#E$ to the power of $\#F$, not the set of functions from $\#F$ to $\#E$).

This shows up in Halmos's *Naive Set Theory* book (p.53) without proof. I attempted to prove this in the following way:

Since both $E$ and $F$ are finite, there exist bijections $e: E\to\#E$ and $f:F\to\#F$. Let $z: E^F \to \{\textrm{all functions from $\#F$ to $\#E$}\}$ where $(x,y)\in z$ iff $(u,v)\in x \iff (f(u),e(v))\in y$.

Now all that's left to prove is that:

1. $z$ is a function.
2. $z$ is a bijection. (i.e a surjection and an injection.)
3. $\{\textrm{all functions from $\#F$ to $\#E$}\}$ is equivalent to $(\#E)^{(\#F)}$

Proof of 1:

It is necessary and sufficient to show that $(r,s),(r,t)\in z \iff s=t$. The first membership means $(u,v)\in r \iff (f(u),e(v))\in s$ and the second means $(u,v)\in r \iff (f(u),e(v))\in t$. Thus, $(f(u),e(v))\in s \iff (f(u),e(v))\in t$ and thereby $s=t$.

Proof of 2:

It is necessary and sufficient to show that $(r,t),(s,t)\in z \iff r=s$ to show that $z$ is an injection. The first membership means $(u,v)\in r \iff (f(u),e(v))\in t$ and the second means $(u,v)\in s \iff (f(u),e(v))\in t$. Therefore $(u,v)\in r \iff (u,v)\in s$ and $r=s$.

**How do I show that $z$ is a surjection?**

**How do I show 3.?**

Comment: Showing 3. is basically the essential part here. A function $F\to E$ can assign any element of $E$ independently for each element of $F$: when fixing an enumeration of $F$ (a bijection $f:F\to #F$), functions $F\to E$ can be represented as a sequence of elements of $E$ of length $#F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a bit of thinking, I think I'll be able to answer my question.

First, the surjection part: for any function $h$ in $\{\textrm{all functions from $\#F$ to $\#E$}\}$, we may construct a function $k$ in $E^F$ where for every $(u,v) \in h$ we have $(f^{-1}(u), e^{-1}(v))\in k$. Due to the bijectivity of $f$ and $e$, $k$ is also a function if $h$ is one. Thus, there always exists $k$ for every $h$, that is, $z$ is surjective.

Next, I make the claim that $\{\textrm{all functions from $n$ to $m$}\} \sim m^{n}$, and I shall prove it by induction on $n$. The only function from $0$ to $m$ is $\varnothing \to \varnothing$, hence $\{\textrm{all functions from $0$ to $m$}\} \sim m^{0}=1$. Now, for any function $h: n \to m$, there are $m$ functions $n^{+}\to m$. This is shown by defining $k_{i}$:

$$k_{i}(x)=\begin{cases} 
      h(x) & 0\leq x<n \\
      i & x=n
   \end{cases}
$$

Clearly there are $m$ such functions based on $h$ ($k_{1},...,k_{m}$), thus, assuming $\{\textrm{all functions from $n$ to $m$}\} \sim m^{n}$,

$$\{\textrm{all functions $n^{+}\to m$}\}\sim m^{n}\cdot m = m^{n^{+}}$$

Thus, by induction, $\{\textrm{all functions from $n$ to $m$}\} \sim m^{n}$ for all natural numbers $m,n$.

(3.) follows swiftly, as

$$E^F \sim \{\textrm{all functions from $\#F$ to $\#E$}\}\sim (\#E)^{(\#F)}$$